# Google Maps (javascript API): get GPS coordinates from address

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to calculate the distance between two addresses and I don't need a map view or anything graphical.

I simply want the user to type in the address (end location is defined by myself) and let the javascript calculate the distance between the two points.

However I don't find a way to send an address string and get the GPS-coordinates from it using the Google Maps API.

(I really only need the two GPS points, the distance calculation is trivial.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called geocoding. It is possible with the Maps API. See the [Geocoding section](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html) for more details. This is the basic idea:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
    "address": inputAddress
}, function(results) {
    console.log(results[0].geometry.location); //LatLng
});
```

**However**, you are limited to 2500 geocoding requests a day, and what you are trying to do is against the terms of use:

> Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google
>   map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

Comment: Not necessarily true.  Google allows you to look up addresses without Maps if you provide proper branding.

Comment: example JSON output: http://pastebin.com/M1bv8u3Z ; it's long so it helps to see it spaced out

Comment: console.log(results[0].geometry.location.toString());

Comment: The language has been updated. `You can display Geocoding API results on a Google Map, or without a map. If you want to display Geocoding API results on a map, then these results must be displayed on a Google Map. It is prohibited to use Geocoding API data on a map that is not a Google map.`

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://expertnotfound.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/fetching-google-maps-search-results-with-java/) describes a Google JSON service that you can extract gps coordinates from. I think this would also be under the "No Use of Content without a Google Map" in the TOS.

Answer (score -2):

This is possible. See below link 
http://briancray.com/posts/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-addresses-with-javascript-and-google-maps-api

Comment: The link is broken